# use private Google spreadsheet as a queryable data table and get the response back as JSON

Tags: android, json, google-sheets

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/google-spreadsheet-as-data-source-android) and referring to [source code here](https://github.com/telerik/Android-samples/tree/master/Blogs/Json-Reader). Got it working for public Google spreadsheet as described. How do I extend this for a private Google spreadsheet? I'm interested in extending this very example and not in alternate ways of achieving this task.